# Codeigniter: How to display a URL of a controller inside a controller (as a sub-url)

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I want to use the controller functions name inside an other one so it will look as if it's a sub-url. How do I do this?

Example:

```
class Food extends CI_Controller {


public function Fruits(){
}

public function apples(){
}

public function bananas(){
}

}
```

currently if I want to call the bananas() function, the url will look like this:

example.com/food/bananasa

And I want it to look like this:

example.com/food/fruits/bananas

example.com/food/fruits/apples

Comment: make food a folder, make fruits the controller and place it inside the food folder

Comment: Oh this is possible? 
and then I can call controllers as `food/fruits/apples` ?

Comment: If this is an option, I think it's the most organized way possible doing this :O

Comment: ya, you can make folders of controllers and the url becomes `site.com/<Folder Name>/<Controller>/<Method>/<Method Arg1>/<Method Arg2>/<Metho....`

Comment: or you could go through the process of creating a [`_remap`](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#remapping) method

Comment: WOW, Thanks, That organizes my code parts a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create `$route` definitions like @Abdulla stated, or you can restructure your controller folder changing this:

```
controllers
  -> food.php
  -> animals.php
```

to this:

```
controllers
  -> food
     -> fruits.php
     -> vegetables.php
  -> animals
     -> pets.php
     -> wild.php
```

doing so will turn your URLs into `site.com/<Folder Name>/<Controller>/<Method>`

Comment: Sure thing, glad i could help!

Answer (score 2):

In `routes.php`

```
$route['food/fruits/bananas'] = 'food/bananasa';
$route['food/fruits/apples'] = 'food/apples';
```

add like these

Answer (score 1):

If you have a permanent structure, 
**Remapping** function should be good for your changing code.

```
public function _remap($method)
{
    if ($method == 'some_method')
     {
        $this->$method();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->default_method();
    }
}
```

Reference : https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html?highlight=remap#remapping-method-calls

For addition : you can use parent class to make it is constructor then calling

```
parent::__construct();
```

in your class.